# HTML dynamic table - stop expand height when insert text

Tags: html, css

I've dynamic table with fixed width and height. Using random function I get numbers of cells (3x3 - 7x7). Table is rendering well. On each cell I've click event which write one letter to pointed cell. There a problem, because row is expanding on height. How to stop it?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PdrNVM

```js
let table = document.getElementById('table');

let tableSize = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 3);

console.log(tableSize);
for (i = 0; i < tableSize; i++) {
    let tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for (j = 0; j < tableSize; j++) {
        let td = document.createElement('td');
        let content = document.createTextNode('');
        td.appendChild(content);
        tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    table.appendChild(tr);
}

let tds = document.querySelectorAll("td");

tds.forEach((td) => {
    td.addEventListener("click", function() {
        td.innerHTML = 'p';
    });
});
```

```css
table {
    width: 200 px;
    height: 200 px;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<h2>Click in cell</h2>
<table id='table'></table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just set a proper `height` and `max-height` like:

```
td {
    background-color: green;
    height: 50px;
    max-height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: I didn't know height of row because it's created dynamically depends of cells quantity

Comment: If that's the case, you can apply different classes, according to your needs, like `cell-7x7` or `cell-3x3`.

Comment: Hi, Your answer is good, but when I tried it I saw some unexpected behaviour. Added class (7x7 is only for example) with fixed height + max-height prevents expanding cell when clicking but why size isn't correct (look in debugger)?
Look: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PdrbLM

Answer (score 0):

Set a fixed height for the tds. You don't need use the height for the table, let the child td make up the height.

```
table {
    width: 200px;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
td {
    height: 60px;
    background-color: green;
}
```